# Android get how much battery used by process?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, batterylevel

I want to get how much battery used by a process. I know how to get levels of battery but percentage is not sensitive enough for my processes. Is there a way to increase scale like 100000 or something bigger than 100? This way i believe i can get the difference accurate.

This is my pseudo code;

```
levelStart = getLevel();
someTestProcess();
levelEnd = getLevel();
result = levelEnd - levelStart;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to get how much battery used by a process

You will have to build your own phone from scratch, or purchase one of the [Qualcomm MDP devices](https://developer.qualcomm.com/mobile-development/development-devices) and use [Trepn](https://developer.qualcomm.com/mobile-development/development-devices/trepn-profiler) (rather than your own code) for power measurement. Standard Android hardware does not have the means of measuring power consumption with much precision.